# TwitterResponse causes hang on Silverlight

Tags: vb.net, silverlight, silverlight-oob, twitterizer

Whenever I try and make any Twitter request, my application always hangs.  This does not apply to the oAuthUtility though, I have successfully authorized the user to use my application, but whenever I make a request it just hangs.  Here is one of the requests I am making that hangs:

```
        Dim response As TwitterResponse(Of TwitterStatus) = TwitterStatus.Update(myFire_tokens.Tokens, TextBox1.Text)
    If response.Result <> RequestResult.Success Then
        MessageBox.Show(response.ErrorMessage, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Tweet Sent", "Awesome!", MessageBoxButton.OK)
    End If
```

This hang occurs on Version 2.4, and releases: 504, 516, and 523.  On Silverlight 5 and 4.  The problem I belive lies with TwitterResponse because the method does get called (For example if I ran the above code, the tweet would post) because I can see a OK response in Fiddler.

**No exceptions are thrown in the debugger, the application just hangs.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should link against the SilverlightAsync project.

If you are on the Silverlight-side, it would have used this signature:

```
public static IAsyncResult Update(
    OAuthTokens tokens, 
    string text, 
    StatusUpdateOptions options, 
    TimeSpan timeout, 
    Action<TwitterAsyncResponse<TwitterStatus>> function)
```

notice the additional two parameters?

Your code should look something like this

```
TwitterStatus.Update(
    myFire_tokens.Tokens, 
    TextBox1.Text, 
    Nothing, 
    0,
    Sub (response As TwitterAsyncResponse<TwitterStatus>)
        If response.Result <> RequestResult.Success Then
            MessageBox.Show(response.ErrorMessage, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK)
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Tweet Sent", "Awesome!", MessageBoxButton.OK)
        End If
    End Sub)
```